# Javafx 8 3D Complex Shape

Tags: javafx

I want to create complex shape like human bodys for my game project. Can  I create complex shape in javafx 8 with trianglemesh. and also i read, it is possible to import 3ds model to javafx. can any one tell me how to import them and do things like rotate move by javafx code

thanks for your help

Comment: As @Itachi says, better to use 3d sdks or if you want to improve your hands on JavaFX. then go ahead. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Also, If you go to Oracle, a 3DViewer is in the jfx samples which will export the 3d file to FXML, thus creating appropriate Groups ... Also being able to re-import the FXML into the Viewer...
[Samples ...](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Although as the above comment stated, InteractiveMesh has some nice tools.

Thats the easy way, if you already have a 3d file... otherwise the point,texCoord, and face arrays can be quite daunting. 
It took me quite a while to create a torus .. points were fine, texCoords were fine, the faces are a pain...

this was just for my customizable torus

```
/*
 Let the radius from the center of the hole to the center of the torus tube be "c", 
 and the radius of the tube be "a". 
 Then the equation in Cartesian coordinates for a torus azimuthally symmetric about the z-axis is
 (c-sqrt(x^2+y^2))^2+z^2=a^2
 and the parametric equations are
 x = (c + a * cos(v)) * cos(u)  
 y = (c + a * cos(v)) * sin(u)  
 z =  a * sin(v)    
 (for u,v in [0,2pi). 

 Three types of torus, known as the standard tori, are possible, 
 depending on the relative sizes of a and c. c>a corresponds to the ring torus (shown above), 
 c=a corresponds to a horn torus which is tangent to itself at the point (0, 0, 0), 
 and c<a corresponds to a self-intersecting spindle torus (Pinkall 1986). 
 */
public static TriangleMesh createToroidMesh(float radius, float tRadius, int tubeDivisions, int radiusDivisions) {
    int POINT_SIZE = 3, TEXCOORD_SIZE = 2, FACE_SIZE = 6;
    int numVerts = tubeDivisions * radiusDivisions;
    int faceCount = numVerts * 2;
    float[] points = new float[numVerts * POINT_SIZE],
            texCoords = new float[numVerts * TEXCOORD_SIZE];
    int[] faces = new int[faceCount * FACE_SIZE],
          smoothingGroups;

    int pointIndex = 0, texIndex = 0, faceIndex = 0, smoothIndex = 0;
    float tubeFraction = 1.0f / tubeDivisions;
    float radiusFraction = 1.0f / radiusDivisions;
    float x, y, z;

    int p0 = 0, p1 = 0, p2 = 0, p3 = 0, t0 = 0, t1 = 0, t2 = 0, t3 = 0;

    // create points
    for (int tubeIndex = 0; tubeIndex < tubeDivisions; tubeIndex++) {

        float radian = tubeFraction * tubeIndex * 2.0f * 3.141592653589793f;

        for (int radiusIndex = 0; radiusIndex < radiusDivisions; radiusIndex++) {

            float localRadian = radiusFraction * radiusIndex * 2.0f * 3.141592653589793f;

            points[pointIndex]     = x = (radius + tRadius * ((float) Math.cos(radian))) * ((float) Math.cos(localRadian));
            points[pointIndex + 1] = y = (radius + tRadius * ((float) Math.cos(radian))) * ((float) Math.sin(localRadian));
            points[pointIndex + 2] = z = (tRadius * (float) Math.sin(radian));

            pointIndex += 3;

            float r = radiusIndex < tubeDivisions ? tubeFraction * radiusIndex * 2.0F * 3.141592653589793f : 0.0f;
            texCoords[texIndex] = (0.5F + (float) (Math.sin(r) * 0.5D));;
            texCoords[texIndex + 1] = ((float) (Math.cos(r) * 0.5D) + 0.5F);

            texIndex += 2;

        }

    }
    //create faces        
    for (int point = 0; point < (tubeDivisions) ; point++) {
        for (int crossSection = 0; crossSection < (radiusDivisions) ; crossSection++) {
            p0 = point * radiusDivisions + crossSection;
            p1 = p0 >= 0 ? p0 + 1 : p0 - (radiusDivisions);
                p1 = p1 % (radiusDivisions) != 0 ? p0 + 1 : p0 - (radiusDivisions - 1);
            p2 = (p0 + radiusDivisions) < ((tubeDivisions * radiusDivisions)) ? p0 + radiusDivisions : p0 - (tubeDivisions * radiusDivisions) + radiusDivisions ;
            p3 = p2 < ((tubeDivisions * radiusDivisions) - 1) ? p2 + 1 : p2 - (tubeDivisions * radiusDivisions) + 1;
                p3 = p3 % (radiusDivisions) != 0 ? p2 + 1 : p2 - (radiusDivisions - 1); 

            t0 = point * (radiusDivisions) + crossSection;
            t1 = t0 >= 0 ? t0 + 1 : t0 - (radiusDivisions);
                t1 = t1 % (radiusDivisions) != 0 ? t0 + 1 : t0 - (radiusDivisions - 1);
            t2 = (t0 + radiusDivisions) < ((tubeDivisions * radiusDivisions)) ? t0 + radiusDivisions : t0 - (tubeDivisions * radiusDivisions) + radiusDivisions ;
            t3 = t2 < ((tubeDivisions * radiusDivisions) - 1) ? t2 + 1 : t2 - (tubeDivisions * radiusDivisions) + 1;
                t3 = t3 % (radiusDivisions) != 0 ? t2 + 1 : t2 - (radiusDivisions - 1);

            try {
                faces[faceIndex]     = (p2);
                faces[faceIndex + 1] = (t3);
                faces[faceIndex + 2] = (p0);
                faces[faceIndex + 3] = (t2);
                faces[faceIndex + 4] = (p1);
                faces[faceIndex + 5] = (t0);

                faceIndex += FACE_SIZE;

                faces[faceIndex]     = (p2);
                faces[faceIndex + 1] = (t3);
                faces[faceIndex + 2] = (p1);
                faces[faceIndex + 3] = (t0);
                faces[faceIndex + 4] = (p3);
                faces[faceIndex + 5] = (t1);
                faceIndex += FACE_SIZE;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    TriangleMesh localTriangleMesh = new TriangleMesh();
    localTriangleMesh.getPoints().setAll(points);
    localTriangleMesh.getTexCoords().setAll(texCoords);
    localTriangleMesh.getFaces().setAll(faces);


    return localTriangleMesh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider it to be a personal opinion.

Though, I don't question the power of Javafx and the `possibility to build complex 3d models using Javafx`, `I would not` suggest building such `complex structures` using it, when you can easily achieve them using `AutoDesk` and other softwares, with less effort !

You have options to import them in your Javafx applications using `early access` available here

http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html

This seems to be very promising !

have a look at this as well

http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dbrowser.html

Answer (score 1):

I made a 2x6 in sketchup and imported it along with the chick/dude/androgyne.  He/she/it is only 2D.  You need to get the jar file [(jimColModelImporterJFX.jar) here.](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html)

```
import com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.Viewpoint;
import com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.col.ColAsset;
import com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.col.ColModelImporter;
//import com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.stl.StlMeshImporter;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;

public class Importer3D extends Application {
    //you'll have to make your own file in sketchup and save it as *.dae
    //http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/114347
    private static final String DAE_FILENAME = ("2x6stud-1.dae");

    private static final int VIEWPORT_SIZE = 800;

    private Group root;

    public Rotate rx = new Rotate();
    { rx.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS); }
    public Rotate ry = new Rotate();
    { ry.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS); }
    public Rotate rz = new Rotate();
    { rz.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS); }
    Translate t = new Translate();

    static Node[] loadNodes() {
        File file = new File(DAE_FILENAME);
        ColModelImporter importer = new ColModelImporter();
        importer.read(file);
        Node[] nodes = importer.getImport();

        ColAsset colAsset = importer.getAsset();
        System.out.println("asset title " + colAsset.getTitle());
        System.out.println("asset unit name " + colAsset.getUnitName());
        System.out.println("asset unit meter " + colAsset.getUnitMeter());
        System.out.println("asset up axis " + colAsset.getUpAxis());
        Map<String, PhongMaterial> materials = importer.getNamedMaterials();
        for (Map.Entry<String, PhongMaterial> e : materials.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("phong material " + e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
        }
        Map<String, Node> namedNodes = importer.getNamedNodes();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Node> e : namedNodes.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("nodes " + e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
        }
        Viewpoint[] viewpoints = importer.getViewpoints();
        if (viewpoints != null) for (Viewpoint v : viewpoints) {
                System.out.println("viewpoint " + v);
            }

        return nodes;
    }

    private Group buildScene() {
        Node[] nodes = loadNodes();
        root = new Group(nodes);
        return root;
    }

    private PerspectiveCamera addCamera(Scene scene) {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        camera.getTransforms().addAll(t, rz, ry, rx);

        camera.setVerticalFieldOfView(true);
        camera.setFieldOfView(10d);
        System.out.println("Near Clip: " + camera.getNearClip());
        System.out.println("Far Clip:  " + camera.getFarClip());
        System.out.println("FOV:       " + camera.getFieldOfView());

        scene.setCamera(camera);
        return camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group group = buildScene();
        group.setScaleX(10);
        group.setScaleY(10);
        group.setScaleZ(10);
        group.setTranslateX(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);
        group.setTranslateY(VIEWPORT_SIZE / 2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, VIEWPORT_SIZE, VIEWPORT_SIZE, true);
        scene.setFill(Color.rgb(10, 10, 40));
        addCamera(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Collada importer");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        scene.setOnKeyPressed((evt) -> {
            switch (evt.getCode()) {
                case UP:
                    rx.setAngle(rx.getAngle() + 5);
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    rx.setAngle(rx.getAngle() - 5);
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    t.setX(t.getX() + 10);
                    //camera.setTranslateX(camera.getTranslateX()+10);
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    t.setX(t.getX() - 10);
                    //camera.setTranslateX(camera.getTranslateX()-10);
                    break;
                case Z:
                    double zoom = evt.isShortcutDown() ? -10 : +10;
                    t.setZ(t.getZ() + zoom);
                    //camera.setTranslateZ(camera.getTranslateZ()+zoom);
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("prism.dirtyopts", "false");
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]